# Why we are using ephemeralSessionConfiguration here?

Tags: ios, nsurlsession

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
    if (self.photoDatabaseContext) {
        NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration ephemeralSessionConfiguration];
        sessionConfig.allowsCellularAccess = NO;
        sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForRequest = BACKGROUND_FLICKR_FETCH_TIMEOUT;
        NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig];
        NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[FlickrFetcher URLforRecentGeoreferencedPhotos]];
        NSURLSessionDownloadTask *task = [session downloadTaskWithRequest:request
                                                        completionHandler:^(NSURL *localFile, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                            if (error) {
                                                                NSLog(@"Flickr background fetch failed: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                                                                completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
                                                            } else {
                                                                [self loadFlickrPhotosFromLocalURL:localFile
                                                                                       intoContext:self.photoDatabaseContext
                                                                               andThenExecuteBlock:^{
                                                                                   completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
                                                                               }
                                                                 ];
                                                            }
                                                        }];
        [task resume];
    } else {
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
    }
}
```

It seems logical that there must be  `backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier` instead of `ephemeralSessionConfiguration` because it is loading in the background. But Paul Hegarty from Stanford iOS course said that second is better. Why? He said something about discrete fetching, but I didn't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ephemeralSessionConfiguration**: Similar to the default configuration, except that all session-related data is stored in memory. Think of this as a “private” session.
**backgroundSessionConfiguration**: Lets the session perform upload or download tasks in the background. Transfers continue even when the app itself is suspended or terminated.
more info :https://www.raywenderlich.com/110458/nsurlsession-tutorial-getting-started